# How to use Laravel URL::asset with a javascript variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel

I'm trying to create an html tag using the following Jquery

```
$("<option />",{ 'data-src':"{{ asset(my-javascript-variable) }}", id:'my_id').appendTo($('#image'));
```

This is an option tag which I am appending to a select. This is occurring on the success of an ajax call within a for loop.

How can I construct a URL using the `asset()` method with a javascript variable? Is this even possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not do that, since PHP will be executed and interpreted first and then the browser will interpret javascript.

But you can try this:

```
var myJavascriptVariable = 'blank.jpg';
$("<option />",{ "data-src": `{{ asset('img/') }}${myJavascriptVariable}`, "id": "my_id"}).appendTo($('#image'));
```

Or

```
var baseUrl = "{{ asset('img/') }}";
var myJavascriptVariable = 'blank.jpg';
$("<option />",{ "data-src": `${ baseUrl + myJavascriptVariable}`, "id": "my_id"}).appendTo($('#image'));
```